# Google maps example not working

Tags: google-maps

I'm trying to run a simple google maps example (this is the example: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple-async). I put the code in my .hmtl file but I`m getting a blank page. And, of course this seems to happen with all google examples (I save all my files on ANSI format).

The code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html>   <head>

<title>Asynchronous Loading</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script>
    function initialize()
    {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    }

    function loadScript()
    {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<MY_CODE>&sensor=false&callback=initialize';
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }

    window.onload = loadScript;

</script>   </head>   <body>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>   </body> </html>
```

Comment: You specify key= in the URL to the API, but you don't bother putting a value for it.  Either add a key value, or don't put key in the URL if you're not using one.

Comment: Do you NEED to load the map file asynchronously?  If not, there's much simpler ways to do this without the use of callbacks

Comment: I put my key there. This is only an example, but for my allexamples seems to show only a blank page :( I also tried to load the JS from the head section...the same behavior.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Blank page when I use FusionTablesLayer with Google Maps JavaScript API v3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789004/blank-page-when-i-use-fusiontableslayer-with-google-maps-javascript-api-v3)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Map not displaying on url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302794/map-not-displaying-on-url)

Answer (score 1):

On that Google example they also include a link to a CSS file.  You don't have any CSS (either inline or external) in the code you've put into the answer.

Look at their CSS file, you'll need something similar:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css

Comment: Thanks! This css was the problem