# Going through Google Maps API tutorial, stuck at first step, example has problems

Tags: google-maps

I am experimenting with google maps API because I will need to integrate them in my website.

I simply copied and pasted the code from here in a page:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple.

I took the code from the Javascript and HTML tab and simply copied into a blank html file.
By doing so, only the input text box and Geocode button appear.

It is not a browser issue because I tried more than one. I got no obvious errors on the page by checking it with Firefly in Opera.

I also put an alert at the end of every function and they all seem called when expected. The alerts have been removed in case somebody wants to take a look at the code in my page.

I am not able to be more specific, because I have only started to look at the map API today and don't know my way around that much.

My page with the copied and pasted code is here:

http://velositeraptor.com/gymfit/trainer/geotest.html

It would be helpful if somebody helped me through the first step so I could take it from there.

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of problems?  Can you extrapolate?

Comment: Yes, apologies but I accidentally submitted right after starting. I am still working on the proper description of the issue.

Comment: I thought so, I didn't give the Downvote.

Comment: Sure @KirkBackus - I wouldn't have taken it personal anyway :) But thanks for letting me knwo...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google maps example not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622265/google-maps-example-not-working)

Comment: I can promise you the example code does work.  If it doesn't then you forgot something.  Make sure you have set the API key the correct way.  Often times it takes a programmer more then a day to figure something out.

Comment: @Ramhound - I am fully aware it takes a while to work something out - but a completely blank page from an example you are supposed to copy and paste is not a very good start for somebody who doesn't know his / her way around :)

Comment: I am not sure how to submit posts in a proper box instead of these small comment here - But the problem is in the css link in the head, which has a relative path instead of an absolute one. The solution is either changing the one in the example to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css , or setting the height and width of the div with id = "map-canvas". No idea how to mark this thread as solved

Comment: @geocodezip Thanks, the solution was the same as that mentioned in the link you provided. I did some searching before posting, but I didn't come across that link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On viewing your source code, it seems **your path reference to the stylesheet is wrong**.

```
<link href="/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

check your browser console for this error.

> **Error:** Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request) 
>   http://velositeraptor.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css

---

`width` and `height` are mandatory for the Google map's div (**`#map-canvas`**), remaining things works perfectly.

check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/DXYuV/).

Better go with ***inline styles*** like

```
<div id="map-canvas" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"></div>
```

Hope you understand.

Comment: Thanks @user1671639. I did work it out in the end, thanks to the other link in one of the previous comments. In one of my small comments above I did say it was resolved, but I really really did not know how to flag the thread as answered. I don't know if it is a bug in SO which didn't allow me to do it myself, and doesn't always allow me to post proper comments ( but only these small things here, if it's intentional I can't see the reasoning behind it ). Anyway, apologies for making you solve something which I had already worked out, and thanks for the time you took to help me out!